# Analyzing a dump file using WinDbg

Tags: windows, dump, windbg, hook

I've been asked to explore a dump file (no source files given) using windbg and to extract some information from it:

- determine what is the issue (hang/crash)
- what module causes the hang.
- What is the root cause of the hang/crash.
- Enumerate all company modules injected to the process
- Enumerate all the hooks done in the process by Company modules

The only file I have is this dmp file.
I am working on Windows10 64bit.

I am working on it for a while already:

1. First of all, I used **.sympath** and **.reload** to verify microsoft symbols are being loaded.
2. Then I used **.analyze! -v** to create an analysis of the file.
3. In this analysis I found the following:

   a.  There was a Break instruction exception 80000003 on thread 7030

   b.  The exception was on a power point process of Microsoft Office 2010.

   c.  The exception was on CpupSyscallStub method

   d.  The module is wow64cpu.

   e.  Because it is a 0x80000003 exception, it is an indication of a manually generated application dump.

   f.  I used **~** command to see the list of threads in the process. All of them were unfrozen.
   g.  However – I used **!runaway** and saw that thread 7030 was up for more than 7 minutes and much more than other threads in the process.

   i.  So maybe it is an hang situation. I am not sure since I guess also that the first thread in list is the main thread, and naturally it may have more process time.

   h.  The root cause is probably “One or more arguments are invalid” as set in the value of EXCEPTION_CODE key.

   i.  Using **~#** should have given me the thread that caused the exception:

   ```
    .  0  Id: 5cf8.7030 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000000`00c5b000 Unfrozen Start:
    *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export  symbols for POWERPNT.EXE -    POWERPNT+0x10c8 (00000000`2d7710c8)
    Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: f
   ```

   j.  But, calling **-ecxr** plotted: “Minidump doesn't have an exception context”, so I am confused…
4. To find injections:

   a.  I used **.hideinjectedcode off** hoping now **!analyze -v** will give me injection information. But I got the same analysis logs…

   b.  Using **lm -v** gave me a list of all modules in the process. 
       So the injected modules are likely to be all the 14 DLLs which has the attribute “CompanyName:      ”, 
       and maybe also the 2 “OpenSSL Project” DLLs which the injecting company might be a partner of it.

   But I am not sure of that...
5. And to find out hook functions I tried to view all injecting company DLLs import 
   tables to find hook functions, After 6-7 DLL’s I didn’t find such. 
   So I gave up this method…

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jSXwXC-tCAD73AMkGVoxA4vqjWtTa5RE) you can find an !analize command output.

As you can see, I did invested much time on this drill.
But reached no clear conclusions.
Your assistance will be most valuable.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you post the dump for us to analyze? You will not get anywhere analyzing the exception as this is a manually created dump as you say. The exception has nothing to do with what the process is hung up on. If it crashed, there would be no process to analyze - it crashed. fwiw - A better tool for analyzing hangs is Etw (but it requires getting used  to analyzing - not my cup of tea either)

Comment: Thank you Lieven, Wow, it is a 1GB file zipped to 300MB... Will the "!analyze -v" output suffice?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt. You can also try `!analyze -v -hang` and try [debugdiag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) automated dump analysis.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jSXwXC-tCAD73AMkGVoxA4vqjWtTa5RE

Comment: I can see there "BusyHang". Is this a proof of hanging??

Comment: It's proof of at least one thread being stuck in a loop. If it's your main thread, the whole application appears [frozen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marklon/2005/08/12/hanged-if-you-do-hanged-if-you-dont/). (I can't open the attachment, that'll have to wait until I get home)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70105/discussion-between-dushkin-and-lieven-keersmaekers).

Comment: you can't debug powerpoint crashes, Microsoft doesn't provide the debug symbols (PDBs) for Office. you get this wow64 noise because used 64bit taskmgr to generate a dump for 32bit office

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks Andre! So, can I detect hangs? Is "BusyHang" implies hang situation?

Comment: you can't really debug it without the debug files.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - There's no way other than capturing a dump with the right bitness to get anywhere with the current dump?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers maybe the [!locks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-a-deadlock) command helps, but maybe it also needs PDBs

Answer (score 0):

First try running CMD and then -
**SC** for service control command
**SYSTEMINFO**  - List system configuration

See what is in output and is there something for your crash

Comment: Thank you Stef. Do you mean windows cmd? Because the dump wasn't created on a system I have access to...

Comment: Yeah i ment the command prompt - Start button - run - "CMD"

Comment: So you have another problem - give this to your system admin, if you don't have access - http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=analyze

Comment: I have no Sysadmin to work with.  It is an task I received as an exercise...  :(

Comment: Ок, then try it your self, but remember, analyzing a dump file is not an easy task. You might need a tool to do some job for you - search the web for       "dump file analyzing tool"

Comment: Now if you excuse me, I really need to smoke !

Comment: Thank Stef for your tips. I already tried OSR site but unfortunately, my dump file size is 1GB... This is what I got and OSR doesn't support this size :(

Comment: Then search and find a God F^&*ng damn tool, download it and install it, so you don't have to use on line one

Comment: I was hoping Windbg is the one...

Comment: As i red it is crap